# When a two-generated ideal of a noetherian integral domain have a finite projective resolution?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, projective-module, noetherian, flatness

Let $R$ be a noetherian integral domain, and $I$ a non-zero ideal of $R$ which can be generated by two elements. (We do not know if $I$, considered as an $R$-module, is $R$-projective; maybe yes maybe no).

**My question:** Can one somehow tell when such $I$ has a finite projective resolution?

Of course, if $I$ is $R$-flat, then it is $R$-projective (remember $R$ is noetherian), so it has a projective resolution of length $0$.

**EDIT:** 
(1) Demanding that $R$ has a finite global dimension is NOT an answer I am looking for.

(2) Demanding that $R$ is a UFD is NOT an answer I am looking for; please see [The G-function of Macrae](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=LYEW3EBvQSgC&pg=PA854&lpg=PA854&dq=david%20rush%20the%20g%20function&source=bl&ots=gECRaC23cf&sig=w3eiq_4jvy6lf1ZlZt4c_cvGJN4&hl=en&sa=X&ei=-piQVZuQBImsU4j4gHA&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=david%20rush%20the%20g%20function&f=false), Theorem 4.10 and Corollary 4.11.
(4.10 says: $R$ is a UFD iff every two-generated ideal has a finite free resolution. 4.11 says: If every two-generated ideal has a finite projective resolution, then $R$ is integrally closed. I adjusted 4.10 to the noetherian case).

See also: [If $R$ is a noetherian local ring, then every 2-generated ideal has finite projective dimension iff $R$ is a UFD](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/802747/if-r-is-a-noetherian-local-ring-then-every-2-generated-ideal-has-finite-proje)

Comment: If $I$ is generated by a regular sequence (of length 2), then $I$ has projective dimension atmost 1.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks! Do you have a reference for that result? (maybe it's in the book of Bruns and Herzog "Cohen-Macaulay rings"?).

Comment: If $I=(a,b)$, for a regular sequence $a,b$, you have a surjection $R^2\to I$ given by $a,b$. One easily checks that the kernel is a free module of rank one generated by the vector $(b,-a)$.

Comment: Thank you! Now, given a two-generated ideal $I$, how can I tell if $I$ can be generated by a regular sequence of length 2? or maybe, generally, there is no way to decide this. (In view of the above mentioned Corollary 4.11, if $R$ is not integrally closed, then there exists a two-generated ideal which cannot be generated by a regular sequence of length 2).

Comment: As I have said before, such vague queries have no good answers.

Comment: In most cases you are right, but sometimes I have luck and a vague question of mine gets the answer I wished to get. The reason I am not clearer here (and elsewhere) is that there is a chance that I am not familiar with a known result I should have known, so I prefer to know the general case first and then apply it to my special cases. For me, relevant comments are also helpful. (Anyway, you can write your first comment as a partial answer, if you wish).