# UFD characterization via module theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules

While studying module theory, I bumped into some theorems characterizing commutative ring properties through modules :

Let $A$ be a commutative ring with unity, then

1. $A$ is a field iff every module over $A$ is free.
2. $A$ is a PID iff every submodule $N$ of a free module $M$ over $A$ is free with $rk(N)\leq rk(M)$.
3. $A$ is Noetherian iff $\bigoplus\limits_{i\in I} E_i$ is an injective $A$-module for any family $\{E_i\}_{i\in I}$ of injective $A$-modules.
4. $A$ is Artinian iff $\prod\limits_{i\in I} P_i$ is a projective $A$-module for any family $\{P_i\}_{i\in I}$ of projective $A$-modules.
5. $A$ is an integral domain, then $A$ is Dedekind domain iff every submodule of a projective $A$-module is projective.

I noticed that all the ring properties all are strongly linked to the ideals of $A$ (guess because they're the only submodules of $A$).

Is there any other characterization as above, for example for unique factorization domains (UFD)?

Comment: If $A$ is an integral domain, then $A$ is Prüfer iff f.g. submodules of projective modules are projective iff torsionfree-modules are flat iff submodules off flat modules are flat.

Comment: A ring is von Neumann regular iff all modules are flat.

Comment: For Dedekind rings we have another nice characterisation. An integral domain $A$ is a Dedekind ring iff s an integrally closed, Noetherian domain with Krull dimension one. And for a Dedekind ring $A$, we have that $A$ is a UFD iff it is a PID. This is even nicer.

Comment: I don't believe I've ever seen such a characterization. Being a UFD seems to be pretty intertwined with the internal structure of the ring, so modules may not capture everything.  "ACCP + GCD domain" is kind of close, except I don't think "principal" and "domain" are captured in the category.

Comment: @rschwieb assuming we speak about commutative rings, the ring itself can be recovered by the endomorphisms of the monoidal unit of the category of modules, so I don't see an obstruction to getting these notions from the category. I would think being a prime ideal can be captured categorically (since the product of ideals can be captured), so at least domain will be doable. You will need the tensor product though...

Comment: I think the point is that the UFD property deals with the uniqueness of a  factorization for  the elements of the ring, not about the ideal structure of the ring.  Indeed, there are examples of rings in which every ideal factors uniquely as a product of prime ideals, but the ring is not a UFD. So, I do not see how a possible characterization in terms of ideals/modules could work.

Comment: There is a homological characterization of Noetherian UFDs, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/803483) and references therein

Comment: @JonasLinssen It could be possible... it would be interesting to know.

Comment: @math54321 As far as I see from the answer appearing in there, that characterization only works for local noetherian UFD's, not for noetherian UFD's in general.

Comment: @blascule787 The actual result in Buchsbaum-Eisenbud characterizes UFDs among all Noetherian rings (without any local hypotheses), in terms of 2-generated ideals having a finite free resolution. If the ring is local, then having a finite free resolution is equivalent to finite projective dimension, but not in the non-local case as the answer shows

Comment: @rschwieb Why do you think "principal" is not captured by the category of modules? Here is one characterization: an $R$-module $M$ is a principal ideal if and only if there is a diagram $R \twoheadrightarrow M \hookrightarrow R$

Comment: I should also say that the original result of MacRae (from the link in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1342748)) shows that the property "GCD domain" is equivalent to "any 2-generated ideal has a finite free resolution of length 1". So with ACCP, this characterizes UFDs among all rings

Comment: @math54321 I see, very interesting. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @math54321 Yes, I do not know why I included that.